# Can't get Activity in MediaRouteButton when using CCL(CastCompanionLibrary) for ChromeCast

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

Currently I'm developing ChromeCast by the example CastVideos-android and

CCL(CastCompanionLibrary).

I tried to use the same coding flow as CastVideos-android, but when I Click the CastButton on the ActionBar, there was a null pointer exception (getActivity() and return Null).

I built v7-mediarouter by myself and added some logs for observation,

The modified codes in MediaRouteButton.java

```
private Activity getActivity() {
    // Gross way of unwrapping the Activity so we can get the FragmentManager
    Context context = getContext();
    
    if (context instanceof ContextWrapper) {
        Log.d(TAG, "[getActivity] context instanceof ContextWrapper");
    } else if (context instanceof Activity) {
        Log.d(TAG, "[getActivity] context instanceof Activity");
    }
    while (context instanceof ContextWrapper) {
        if (context instanceof Activity) {
            return (Activity)context;
        }
        context = ((ContextWrapper)context).getBaseContext();
        Log.d(TAG, "[getActivity] getBaseContext = " + context);
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "[getActivity] return null");
    return null;
}
```

The logs showed that:

## 1. For the example CastVideos-android

*03-09 15:35:33.473: D/MediaRouteButton(11409): [getActivity] context = android.view.ContextThemeWrapper@ae4badf*

*03-09 15:35:33.473: D/MediaRouteButton(11409): [getActivity] context instanceof ContextWrapper*

*03-09 15:35:33.473: D/MediaRouteButton(11409): [getActivity] getBaseContext = android.view.ContextThemeWrapper@3bcdb32c*

*03-09 15:35:33.473: D/MediaRouteButton(11409): [getActivity] getBaseContext =com.google.sample.cast.refplayer.VideoBrowserActivity@3a39dcf1*

**And MediaRouteButton can get Activity successfully.**

## 2. For my own app:

*03-09 15:23:46.453: D/MediaRouteButton(7272): [getActivity] context = android.view.ContextThemeWrapper@eb4848*

*03-09 15:23:46.453: D/MediaRouteButton(7272): [getActivity] context instanceof ContextWrapper*

*03-09 15:23:46.453: D/MediaRouteButton(7272): [getActivity] getBaseContext = com.mychromecast.application @1a3e8984*

*03-09 15:23:46.453: D/MediaRouteButton(7272): [getActivity] getBaseContext = android.app.ContextImpl@3e3e6e1*

03-09 15:23:46.453: D/MediaRouteButton(7272): [getActivity] return null

**It got my customized application class and ContextImpl when trying to getBaseContext() rather than ContextThemeWrapper and current activity as the example did.**

**So, it can't get a activity correctly to handle FragmentManager and so on.**

Need your help and thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your activity inheriting from?

Comment: I modified the source code of v7-mediarouter to make it can access Activity rather than ActionBarActivity or FragmentActivity.

So, my App's activity is inheriting android.app.Activity.

Comment: Sorry, since you are not using a standard version of the library, I won't be able to see what is happening to provide any useful feedback. In general, modifying such library and using that in production is a really bad idea, but I am sure you are aware of the risk, etc.

Comment: Yes,I know it's kinda risky. But my App's activity is inheriting some 3rd party customized activity which I can't modify it to use actionbaractivity. Is there any advice that for this case? The super activity is not allowed to use actionbarActivity or fragmentActivity due to existed code structure...? Thank again!

Comment: My only suggestion is to really trace and debug that in the modified version of the library, in run time, and see why it fails.